Install Another Old Version Pyton in Fedora
I followed an very old article guide to install Python3.7 as below on my Fedora 40 Workstation,
nanohe@fedora:~$ sudo su -
[sudo] password for nanohe: 
root@fedora:~# sudo dnf install python37
Last metadata expiration check: 3:25:39 ago on Sat 18 May 2024 07:37:18 PM CST.
No match for argument: python37
Error: Unable to find a match: python37
root@fedora:~# 

Could anybody tell me how to install it with an easier way. Since I already installed a latest version 3.12.3 on the default path of /usr/lib64/. I want to switch different python version in my Python IDE.
I am new to Linux OS and I don't want to compile the source code method since I find some solution that using compile source code method or virtual environment method. Is there any more easier way to achieve it such as yum install xxxx...
Appreciated for you input in advance.
BR
Nano
